# Extend HTMLElement in TypeScript

Tags: html, typescript, extend

I'm trying to extend the HTMLElement in typescript. I tried different methods and they all work, but i keep getting an type-script error:

Argument Sprite is not assignable to parameter type Node;

When i do :

document.body.appendChild(createSprite());

```
interface Sprite extends HTMLElement {

}

function createSprite() : Sprite {

    return <Sprite> document.createElement("div");

}

document.body.appendChild(createSprite());
```

Comment: Your code builds for me. Have you got the latest version of the Typescript Compiler?

Answer (score 0):

I ran this through the [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20Sprite%20extends%20HTMLElement%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createSprite%28%29%20%3a%20Sprite%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%3CSprite%3E%20document.createElement%28%22div%22%29;%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20sprite%20=%20createSprite%28%29;%0D%0Asprite.innerHTML%20=%20%27Test%27;%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild%28sprite%29;) (and added some text so I could see the result) and it works fine:

```
interface Sprite extends HTMLElement {

}

function createSprite() : Sprite {
    return <Sprite> document.createElement("div");
}

var sprite = createSprite();
sprite.innerHTML = 'Test';
document.body.appendChild(sprite);
```